# ¿Cómo especificar en map() o pmap() del package purrr el tipo de variable?

Tags: r, rstudio

Me encuentro con un problema cuando intento realizar algunas funciones y es que únicamente se puede hacer con argumento numérico. La idea que tengo es algo similar a esto

`sd_2<-map2(BBDD_PPLUS, ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE, is.numeric(BBDD_PPLUS)))`

Aunque si realmente fuera posible algo como

`sd_2<-map2(BBDD_PPLUS, ~ f1, f2 ,f3..(.x, na.rm = TRUE, is.numeric(BBDD_PPLUS)))`

De este modo realizaría varias funciones descriptivas sobre una BBDD en aquellas variables numéricas

Comment: Bienvenido Javier Hernando a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

De lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, estás buscando aplicar una serie de funciones estadísticas a las variables de un `data.frame`, ciertamente con `purrr` podrías, pero también podrías lograrlo de una forma, tal vez, un poco más clara usando `dplyr/tidyr`, por ejemplo:

```
library("tidyverse")

mtcars %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  summarize_if(is.numeric, 
               list(min = min, 
                    max = max,
                    sd = sd,
                    v = var,
                    mean = mean)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  separate(name, sep='_', into = c('var', 'stat')) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=stat)

# A tibble: 11 x 6
   var     min    max      sd         v    mean
   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 mpg   10.4   33.9    6.03     36.3    20.1  
 2 cyl    4      8      1.79      3.19    6.19 
 3 disp  71.1  472    124.    15361.    231.   
 4 hp    52    335     68.6    4701.    147.   
 5 drat   2.76   4.93   0.535     0.286   3.60 
 6 wt     1.51   5.42   0.978     0.957   3.22 
 7 qsec  14.5   22.9    1.79      3.19   17.8  
 8 vs     0      1      0.504     0.254   0.438
 9 am     0      1      0.499     0.249   0.406
10 gear   3      5      0.738     0.544   3.69 
11 carb   1      8      1.62      2.61    2.81
```

El calculo en sí lo realiza `summarize_if()` solo sobre las columnas numéricas, y puedes definir una lista de funciones a aplicar, el resto son funciones que usamos para "acomodar" los datos para verlos de una forma más clara.

Comment: La realidad es que necesitaría generar nuevas columnas con los resultados a partir de la variable problema de tal manera

Comment: Me ha generado los siguientes errores                                                                  Warning messages:
1: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 10 rows [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19]. 
2: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

Comment: Posiblemente tenga que ver con que existan filas con valores repetidos, el truco en estos casos es agregar una  columna identificador única por fila, revisa mi edición. Te sugiero también si los problemas persisten que agregues un [mcve]